# How can I connect a PS3 to the Internet with a VPN?

Tags: ps3

I want to know if it's possible for a PS3 to be connected to the internet via a VPN?

Comment: What kind of VPN? A bridged or routed?

Comment: The simple answer is yes, but you need to expand on the detail in your question. I'd recommend a migrate to superuser as this is offtopic here.

Comment: @Krazer a routed one i suppose. But i don't know how to proceed with this.

Comment: @Rory Questions about the operation of game consoles are considered on-topic here, actually.

Comment: @CharmingPrince If you get a crossover cable, connect it to a computer or laptop and PS3. You should be able to shat the connection with you PS3. Take a look at this: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing

Comment: @Mana - ok. Just seems like a purely straightforward networking question to me. My bad.

Comment: @Krazer that was very helpful, i think i know what to do now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you get a crossover cable and connect your PS3 to a computer or laptop. You should be able to share the connection with your PS3.

[Here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing) is a guide on how to enable Internet Connection Sharing on your Windows computer.

Comment: These days, the vast majority of network ports will auto-detect and auto-negotiate crossover; you might not even need the special cable. It's worth trying with a normal Ethernet cable, since it'll take like five minutes and probably won't fry anything.

Comment: Not probably. 100% sure is not going to fry anything :)